# Rails - do a logic operation on each row of an activerecord result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, boolean-logic

I have a model that has a column of type Boolean.

It's possible to retrieve "on the fly" (without iterating all the result) the result of a logic calculus?

For example:

```
data = Model.limit(10)
# I would like to know if each data.column is true
# the result is something to this logic: data[0].column && data[1].column && ...
# ..but there is one manner to do this without iterating?
```

Using the main conditions: AND, OR, XOR (the conditions are all the same - all AND or all OR ,...).

Comment: Maybe you can treat true as 1 and false as 0. You can easily fetch SUM(column). If SUM(column) == Model.count, it means that all records have column = true. If SUM(column) == 0, it means that all are false. You can easily extend solution to return two additional fields, like number_of_trues [ 1 if true, 0 if false ] and number_of_falses [ 0 if true, 1 if false ]. If you want to know, if all are true, just check if number_of_falses is 0 etc

Comment: @mkk this is a good solution if you must build from scratch the model too. If the model already exists I think that is better the solution suggested by Ryan Bigg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
records = Model.limit(10).all
records.all? { |r| r.column? }
```

I think `all?` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it is was I looking for. I'dont known the method "all?"